# Morte bug in Planescape:Torment prevents me ending the game

Tags: planescape-torment

*This is about the end of the game, so obviously there will be spoilers, be warned!*

I am at the end of the game, and tried to do the merging end.

I manage to do it, get the FMV, and merge with the Mortality. Then, TNO goes to resurrect his companions. He starts by resurrecting Morte, and that's it. Morte stands in front of TNO, I can't talk to him, and he is not even part of my group. I can't access his inventory, can't see his stats, he is not in the group characters' bar.

I have tried reloading previous saves several times with no success, and using previous saves didn't help either.

This is very frustrating, as it is the very end of the game... Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: Are you using a vanilla version or did you install fix packs?

Answer (score 1):

I have found something that may help you.

[Lost Party Members Fix](http://planescape.outshine.com/mods/readmeplost.html) from [this thread](http://www.gamespot.com/planescape-torment/forum/morte-problem-spoilers-within-42644083/).

Please inform me if it works.